# FFMPEG zoom-pan multiple images

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to stitch multiple images with some zoom-pan happening on the images to create a video.

Command:-

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -r 30 -t 10 -i \
color=#000000:1920x1080 \
-f lavfi \
-r 30 -t 10 \
-i aevalsrc=0 \
-i "image-1.png" \
-i "image-2.png" \
-y -filter_complex \
"[0:v]fifo[bg];\
[2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+0/TB,scale=4455:2506:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,2.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=150:fps='30':s='1920x1080'[v2];\
[bg][v2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0, 5)'[bg];\
[3:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.07/TB,scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,2.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=150:fps='30':s='1920x1080'[v3];\
[bg][v3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5, 10)'[bg];\
[1:a]amix=inputs=1:duration=first:dropout_transition=0" \
-map "[bg]" -vcodec "libx264" -preset "veryfast" -crf "15" "output.mp4"
```

The output is not as expected, it only zooms only on the first image, the second image is just static.

FFMPEG version - 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=#000000:1920x1080:r=30:d=10 \
       -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc \
       -i "image-1.png" \
       -i "image-2.png" \
       -filter_complex \
"[2:v]scale=4455:2506:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,2.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=150:fps=30:s='1920x1080'[v2];\
 [bg][v2]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[bg];\
 [3:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,2.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=150:fps=30:s='1920x1080',setpts=PTS+5/TB[v3];\
 [bg][v3]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,10)'[bg];\
-map "[bg]" -map 1:a -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 15 -y "output.mp4"
```

For lavfi sources, it's best to set frame rate and duration where applicable within the filter.

Since you're not looping the images, `-t` won't have any effect. Since zoompan will set fps in its output, you can skip input rate setting. And since it's a single image, setpts before zoompan has no relevance. It should be set only on the zoompan whose timestamps need to be shifted.

Since you've only one audio, no point sending it to amix - there's nothing to mix with! Just map it directly.